# How to use variables in an Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to update a verify column hash. It doesn't have to be HR, but for the sql puzzle it's hr, the table is:

```
   DESC SINERS
Name      Null     Type         
--------- -------- ------------ 
LAST_NAME          VARCHAR2(20) 
SIN  NOT NULL NUMBER(9)    
VFY            NUMBER(2)
```

the puzzle is tricky, and requires a bit of code.

> Most payroll systems have a built in validity check for the social
>   insurance number. The following example illustrates how to manually
>   check the validity of a social insurance number: Social Insurance
>   Number: 123 456 782 Remove the check digit (the last digit): 2 Extract
>   the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th digits: 2 4 6 8 Double them: 4 8 12 16 Add
>   the digits together: 4 + 8 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 6 = 22 Add the 1st, 3rd, 5th
>   and 7th digits: 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16 TOTAL: 38

I just made up this table to simulate how to grab a variable from the update or insert statement, calculate an hash... then throw the variable back into the same table.

i.e. ... user runs this :

```
insert into siners (last_name, sin) values (smith, 111222333);

or 

update siners set sin = 222333444 where last_name = 'smith';
```

I looked around the web for examples of how to do this but it is unclear.

Is there an easy way to do this? a function perhaps?

First, I generated the oracle sql code, --- I sub-stringed the crap out of it, but it works.

```
SELECT NVL((NEXT_MULTI - TOTAL_SUM), 0) AS CHECK_VAL
FROM (
SELECT ((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1)))
     "TOTAL_SUM",  
      CASE WHEN SUBSTR(((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1))), 2, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN ((10 - (SUBSTR(((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1))), 2, 1))) + ((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1)))) END AS NEXT_MULTI
FROM SINERS);
```

Second, I tried to make the code into a trigger, and that is where I am stuck at the moment.

I tried to created the trigger with SQL select in it, but it gave me an error, that I couldn't run a select on a row that was being modified. //The trigger compiled fine, but it spat out the error when I ran an insert against the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHK_VFY
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF SIN ON SINERS
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE

LAST_ONE  NUMBER(1); 
TOTAL_SUM  NUMBER(2);  
NEXT_MULTI NUMBER(2);
CHECK_VAL  NUMBER(2);

BEGIN

SELECT T_SUM INTO TOTAL_SUM
FROM (
SELECT ((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1)))
     "T_SUM" FROM SINERS );

SELECT LAST1 INTO LAST_ONE
FROM (
SELECT  SUBSTR(((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SIN, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SIN, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SIN, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SIN, 7, 1))), 2, 1) LAST1 FROM SINERS);

IF LAST_ONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN 
         NEXT_MULTI := (10 - LAST_ONE) + TOTAL_SUM ;
         CHECK_VAL := (NEXT_MULTI - TOTAL_SUM);
  ELSE 
    CHECK_VAL := 0;
END IF;
UPDATE SINERS SET VFY = CHECK_VAL;

END;
```

After a bit of research, on this site, and others, I tried using :new.sin to grab the variable before the update, but had not luck. it doesn't seem to update. So, I dropped in the `dbms_output.put_line( ' Updated Check Value = ' || CHECK_VAL );` to try and verify if the variables were being gathered. I get no output from it at all....

using the :new.variable  code.... It compiles fine, but prompts me for bind variables. "new" The default is null, but I tried playing with the variables as I see some `reference new as new and old as old` in similar examples.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CAL_VFY
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF SIN ON SINERS
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
SINNO NUMBER(9);
LAST_ONE  NUMBER(2); 
TOTAL_SUM  NUMBER(2);  
NEXT_MULTI NUMBER(2);
CHECK_VAL  NUMBER(2);

BEGIN
  SINNO := :NEW.SIN;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'side sin = ' || sinno );
  LAST_ONE := SUBSTR(((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) ) + 
      (  SUBSTR(SINNO, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 7, 1))), 2, 1); 

  TOTAL_SUM := ((
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 1,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 2,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 3,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 4,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 5,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 6,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 7,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 8,1), 0) +
      NVL(SUBSTR( (SUBSTR(SINNO, 2, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 4, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 6, 1)*2) || (SUBSTR(SINNO, 8, 1)*2), 9,1), 0) 
      ) + (  SUBSTR(SINNO, 1, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 3, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 5, 1) + SUBSTR(SINNO, 7, 1))); 

  IF LAST_ONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN 
         NEXT_MULTI := (10 - LAST_ONE) + TOTAL_SUM ;
         CHECK_VAL := (NEXT_MULTI - TOTAL_SUM);
  ELSE 
    CHECK_VAL := 0;
  END IF;

  CASE 
   WHEN INSERTING THEN
           UPDATE SINERS SET VFY = CHECK_VAL WHERE SIN = :NEW.SIN;
           dbms_output.put_line( 'New Check Value = ' || CHECK_VAL );

    WHEN UPDATING THEN
          UPDATE SINERS SET VFY = CHECK_VAL WHERE SIN = :NEW.SIN;
          dbms_output.put_line( ' Updated Check Value = ' || CHECK_VAL );
  END CASE;

END;
```

If you have an thoughts on how to go about this, I'm all ears....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the category is related to the customer in another table already, why do you want to duplicate that link in this table and have to maintain it in two places?

Comment: First, read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  .   Where is this "division" column?  Please show ALL relevant table schemas.

Comment: Actually, all I want is have a trigger calculate the third column when a user update or insert the first two. I tried using the :new. along with the a update, but it didn't work.  It compiles without error, but doesn't run. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use UPDATE statement to update the column of the row that you are inserting/updating. Once the trigger execution is completed, the statements that triggered it will run and do the insert/update.
So, you should simply set the value for the third column.

```
:new.vfy := check_val;
```

No need to use CASE statement here.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just a small question on bind variables.... In the above code, last code, I have the referencing statement, but it still prompts me for bind variables, how do I handle that, or just ignore it.?

Comment: I think you can ignore it.  One more thing, it is not a good idea to edit the question with the answer given by others. You can add an update to the question.